# Display recent posts with thumbnail

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails

I have the following php in a template. This lists the most recent posts.

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post-format-aside',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ), 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post-format-image',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
    ) );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   ( __($recent["post_title"])).'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

How can I make it so that each title displays the featured image of the article to the left of the text? I know that `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` will display the featured image but I am not sure how to incorporate this into the code.

EDIT:
I would also like to display the post date (in human/relative style e.g "posted two days ago"). I also need to style this with a separate CSS class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()` can only be used in "the Loop". What you need is `get_the_post_thumbnail()`. (See details and code examples on the [code reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)).

So something like:

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li>';
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent['ID'], 'size', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   ( __($recent["post_title"])).'</a></li> ';
}
```

Where 'size' is whatever registered thumbnail size you want for the image.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I got it to work now but on the top it says "scheduled" I don't know what line in the code that is causing this, but I guess that the php you gave me calls for post formats somewhere..

Comment: You're probably picking up posts that are scheduled, but not yet published. You can limit to only the most recent published posts by adding `'post_status' => 'publish', ` to the beginning of your `$args`, just before `'numberposts'`.